# CSS mobile: box-shadow doesn't work correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile-browser

When I've opened my site in chrome mobile v48, I've found that `box-shadow: 1px` property behaves weird: the width of the shadow is floating from side to side and ain't the same. I assume it because of fractional device pixel ratio `1.5`:

[image]

The next code fragment does not always gives to me required `1px` shadow but it is floating around `1-3px` sometimes on mobile browsers:

```
div {
   margin: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   padding: 20px;
   width: 40%;
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
...
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/va4LL8qf/2/)

I've tried to use `-webkit` prefix but nothing has been changed. Using an alternative unit `em` instead of `px` one brings nothing as well as fractional values like `0.5px`.

The `viewport` meta tag seems not enough:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

How to fix this and let `box-shadow` property to display correctly on mobile browsers?

Comment: can you test your device [here](http://www.mydevice.io/) and tell me what is your CSS pixel ratio and Device Aspect-Ratio ?

Comment: @dippas, pixel ratio is `1.5`, device aspect ratio is `0.56`

Comment: Ok I've tested your code and mine is 3 and 0.56 and it works fine.

Comment: set border:0; for your element.

Comment: @dippas, I've tried to reproduce the issue at JSFiddle and seems it happened. The initial scale looks wrong, it's so small so it's ok. But during a zoom it's width is floating from side to side:(

Comment: @tnt-rox, still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using any kind of CSS reset? That might help you out.

Have you tried using `media queries`, something like this:

```css
@media(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi) { 
    /* CSS stuff here */
}
```

Comment: Will take a look of CSS reset, thanks. Media queries are not useful for me yet while I have no idea what to put in. The minimal width unit like `1px` gives unexpectable result.

Comment: it's `device-width` in combination with `initial-scale=1`

Comment: have you used shadows for your mobile site versions?

Comment: yes and your code works fine, having CSS pixel ratio 3, device aspect ratio 0.56

Comment: the only browser which renders the shadows properly is FireFox. Seems like it's a bug in rest major browsers. epic

Comment: Ive tested in chrome

Comment: Indeed, with pixel ratio `3` it works fine. So, there're no workarounds at the moment except of disabling `box-shadow` or switching to `border` one for fractional pixel ratio devices using media-queries you have specified due it's 99% a bug.